# jsf compositeComponent stateHelper reset after updating form

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm using a `compositeComponent` in my application which allows a user to input an address. I store some specific data in the `stateHelper` to retreive it afterwards on submitting the form. The problem is when I click my button which submits AND updates the form, the stateHelper value is null. But if I add a panel layer under the form and update this one, they keep their values. Does anyone know how or why this is behaving like this?

ExampleCode (**doesn't work**):

```
...
<form id="inputForm>
    <custComp:inputAddress />
    <p:commandButton value="submitForm" update="inputForm/>
</form>
```

Example code (**works**)

```
<form id="inputForm">
    <p:panel id="inputPanel">
        <custComp:inputAddress />
        <p:commandButton value="submitForm" update="inputPanel" />
    </p:panel>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm using Mojorra JSF 2.2, and Primefaces 5.1 with JBoss 8.1.

Comment: yes mojorra, sorry for being inaccurate